# When sending my final grades to one professional school, my transcript shows I am enrolled in another program

Tags: transcript-of-records

I have been accepted to two professional schools for next year, one of which is part of my current university (Program A). I need to send an official transcript with my final semester's grades to the other school (Program B). Before submitting a request to my current school to send my transcript, I checked my unofficial transcript. I was surprised to see that since I already graduated with my undergraduate degree, the transcript lists that I am currently attending Program A, including the classes I would be enrolled in for the fall semester.

- Does my unofficial transcript reflect how my official transcript will appear?
- If it does list Program A, will Program B regard this as an issue? Or can I just submit my transcript as-is with no explanation?
- If this is an issue, is there a way I can circumvent it?

(Note: I'd like to hold on to both acceptances until nearer to the end of the summer, as Covid-19 might be affecting where I'll be living next year.)

Comment: You need to take this up with the university. There is no common answer.

Comment: Are you referring to my current university, or the other one?

Comment: @Buffy I also don't want my current school to know about the other, especially since my current school is offering me a scholarship.

Comment: You may be able to ask for a "degree" transcript at some universities.

Comment: Just to be clear - you have not officially enrolled in Program A, nor otherwise notified them that you intend to do so?

Comment: @zhantongz thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

> Does my unofficial transcript reflect how my official transcript will appear?

Only your university knows how they handle the two types of transcripts.  But it's possible.

> If it does list Program A, will Program B regard this as an issue? Or can I just submit my transcript as-is with no explanation?

I think it would be reasonable to inform Program B that this is an error and that you have not enrolled in any program at A for the fall semester.

It's true that this might reveal that you have applied and been accepted to A, but I don't think that's a serious concern.  Every university knows that applicants apply to many different programs.

If anything, the fact that you've been accepted to another program would likely motivate B to try *harder* to recruit you, since it's confirmation that you are well qualified for professional study, and it shows B they can't expect you to accept a low financial offer out of desperation.

> If this is an issue, is there a way I can circumvent it?

Sure; contact the office at A responsible for maintaining academic records (e.g. the registrar). Inform them that your transcript erroneously shows you as enrolled in the program, and ask for it to be corrected.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your help and will reach out to the registrar.